# Can any application be deployed with MDT from Applications using Task Sequence?

Tags: windows, mdt

When deploying images with Task Sequence are you able to deploy any .exe/application or are there certain cases where they will not work?

I know with .msi they are designed to be push from AD and can take command line parameters. And with .exe they are basically compiled together from an install application. I just don't know if they are generic or if it depends on which application compiled them.

I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 DC with MDT 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy **ANY** `exe` but the level of automation differs on each program:

Some you will only have a /s switch where as others you will have something like this `setup.exe /s /installdir:[dirname] /desktopico:{y/n} /features:{some junk goes in here}`

And some others will not even have a silent (automated) install option. It is best to use the MSI. Because they are guaranteed to have silent install options. (they are not just for GP they can also be deployed using MDT).

Your best bet is to research the program you want to deploy and see if they offer any automation (most offer at least the /s switch).